# Representation of skillpoints on LaTeX

Tags: latex

I would like to insert a section in my curriculum vitae where my skills are graphically represented. Since the spaces are limited I would like to delete the image that precedes the description of the skill (which in this case is the blue arrow). How could I do ? ps. the original code was not created by me

```
 % uniform icon style for all skill icons, e.g. flags or fontawesome icons
    \newcommand{\cvicon}[1]{\makebox[1em]{\color{iconcolor} #1}}


% \pointskill[<indent>]{<description>}{<points>}[<maxpoints>] creates
% | [indent] description  \hfill  ● ● ● ○ ○ |
% -- inspired by arravc.cls by LianTze Lim: https://github.com/liantze/AltaCV
\NewDocumentCommand{\pointq}{ O{0em} m m m O{5} }{%
    \hspace{#1} \cvicon{#2} ~ #3 \hfill%
    \foreach \x in {1,...,#5}{%
        \space%
        {\ifnumgreater{\x}{#4}{\color{skillbg}}{\color{iconcolor}}% from etoolbox
        % don't use totalheight; see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/41014
        \raisebox{0.5\height-0.4ex}{\scriptsize\faCircle}%
        }
    }\par%
}
```

graphic example of how it looks if I call `\pointskill{►}{Python}{3}` :
[image]

Comment: Please make a [mre]. You don't even tell us which of the hundreds of cv classes and packages you use

Comment: I'm using https://it.overleaf.com/latex/templates/forty-seconds-cv/pztcktmyngsk

Comment: Please make a small, but compilable [mre], starting with the documentclass and ending with `\end{document}`